# How to search specific number using regular expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a comma separated values for each row in table.
Suppose in test table

```
Value
1,5,12
2,4,15
5,2,6
```

I would like to find records with value =5
Using normal ms sql, I had used like operator which gave me all the 3 records. 
Could you please help if can it be possible with regular expression.

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: MySQL you can use : **SELECT ..... WHERE CONCAT(',',`value`,',') LIKE '%,5,%';** - but it is always a FULL TABLE SCAN. see  @ jarlh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: @jarlh I am using mssql

Comment: The table is already created in application. So couldn't change. Using regular expressions whether we can get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this too. Does not look very efficient but working.

```
    /* Create a table called NAMES */
   CREATE TABLE test(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);

  /* Create few records in this table */
 INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,'1,5,12');
 INSERT INTO test VALUES(2,'2,4,15');
 INSERT INTO test VALUES(3,'5,2,6');
 INSERT INTO test VALUES(5,'1,2,5');
-- SELECT * FROM test;

SELECT * from test WHERE Name LIKE '%,5,%' OR 
 Name LIKE '%5,%' OR 
 Name LIKE '%,5%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably already know this is a bad data format and you should fix it.  If you are stuck with it, you can use `like`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM test t
WHERE ',' + Name + ',' LIKE '%,5,%';
```